# What species do the the Freespace 2 Shivans resemble?

Tags: freespace-2

What type of species the Shivans in Freespace 2? The cut scenes made them look like bio-mechanical organisms with but that is about all I could tell. Is there any official story on what they were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Freespace Wiki indicates the Shivans appear to be a type of insectoid race whose origins are outside of Terran Space.**

- The Shivans are a sentient species who likely originated in an unexplored region of space. The first known entry of the Shivans into the known galaxy occurred 8,000 years before the events of FreeSpace, during which the Shivans exterminated a highly advanced civilization, known as the Ancients.
- [TVtropes.com Freespace description](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/FreeSpace?from=Main.Freespace) seemed most appropriate: "The Shivans themselves are physically the largest of all three races, measuring about 10-15 feet long, with spidery limbs, multiple eyes, metal skin, energy-molten knives, built-in beam weapons, and are Immune to Bullets. Not to mention the fact that they glow red."

[image]

**Physiology**

> - Shivans have multiple eyes, some of which seem to have the function of compound eyes, not unlike some varieties of insects. Shivans also have five legs, and can run equally well over a floor or over a ceiling. It has been hypothesized that Shivans may have spent their evolutionary process in a zero-gravity environment.
> - Each Shivan leg ends in a very strong claw, capable of crushing even the sturdiest of known alloys. Parts of their thorax seem to act as compartments, such as ones that might be found on a space suit. It has been suggested that what we have actually seen have been either robots or organic creatures in some sort of exo-skeleton. However, we have, at present, no reason to support either hypothesis.
> - Their insect-like carapace does not appear original to the creature's physiology, suggesting the Shivans are a cybernetic fusion of biology and technology. The integrated plasma weapon also exhibits properties of an organic-artificial fusion. The weapon may be a kind of focusing device powered by the energy of the being itself, though this point is the subject of heated controversy.
> - These details are cited as evidence that the Shivans could not have evolved as the Terran or Vasudan species had, but that they were likely constructed by another entity. Only a handful of Shivans have ever been captured, and all research on live specimens ended with the Galactic Terran Intelligence's (GTI) Hades Rebellion in 2336. The results of these studies remain highly classified. **REF: Freespace Wiki -> [Shivans](http://www.hard-light.net/wiki/index.php/Shivans)**

### Cut Scenes from Freespace 2

The so-called "Great War" with the Shivans ended with the destruction of the Lucifer as it attempted to traverse the Sol sub-space node, intending to destroy Earth. unfortunately this collapsed the node and all contact with Earth was lost.

- The Shivans themselves are shown in a cutscene in this game, they are multi-limbed (at least five) tripedal creatures far larger than a man. The appear to have compound eyes similar to those of insects and have a large laser weapon slung undeneath their chest.
- Their armour also seems to be part of the creature causing many to speculate that these Shivan footsoldiers are either in some kind of exo-skeleton or are robots or drones. In either case the cutscene shows them to be an extremely formidable adversary in combat.

[image]

Comment: This was one of my favorite games back in the day. I still have never been able to find a better space combat simulation game.

Comment: I don't think one has ever existed. I play EVE Online and while the experience is good, it is not quite the same, because you can be so outclassed by an opponent's technology, as to have no chance at all, no matter how skilled a pilot you might be. Freespace was a game I played until my computer wouldn't. Now that I know there is an open source version, I will be testing to see if my System 7 machine can run it. Rumor has it there are also hundreds of new missions created by fan developers.

Comment: You can get it up and running easy with a [download from GoG](http://www.gog.com/gamecard/freespace_2) also if you look here at the [Freespace Source project](http://scp.indiegames.us/) you will see that those rumors are true.  More is available on this [Pcgamer article](http://www.pcgamer.com/2012/12/22/reinstall-freespace-2/) that made me fall in love with Freespace all over again.

Comment: I forgot about the freespace Wiki. Thanks!

Comment: @ryan go check out hard-light.net. There is the freespace 2 open project. They update the source code periodically. They have done wonderful things with graphics as well as non-canon campaigns.